# PowerShell - Select(or regex for) words that ends in .story

Tags: powershell, regex

I am trying to extract from some notes, words that ends in .story. This words are always placed into some links such as `bla:///bla/bla/bla/.../word.story`. The notes may contain multiple links and the format of these notes may vary but there I will always have entries in form of `bla///../..../bla.story`.

Until now I've used the following expression: `[string]$story_name = Select-String \w+..story -input $notes -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches -replace ('\.story','')}` but now I'm facing some issues with this because it seems that if the link contains entries as `bla:///bla/blablaistory/bla/bla/word.story` than this expression will also select that word that contains ***'istory'*** and I do not want this to happen. What I should use in order to avoid this?

Comment: With your above `-replace ('\.story',''` that shouldn't happen as `\.` escapes the dot to match it literal.

Comment: well, it happens :(. check this: `$notes = "alalala/bla//blablahistory/somethingnice.story"
[string]$storyName = Select-String \w+...story -input $notes -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches -replace ('\.story','')}
write-host $storyName`

Comment: there isn't `istory` in the string and if you include it there is no match - so what?

Comment: If you don't want it selected at all include the escaping backslash in the `Select-String \w+.\.story`

Comment: there is `istory` in the string and there is a match - the output of the above commands is: `blablahistory somethingnice` but what i want to have is just `somethingnice`

Comment: hmmm, that might work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$notes = @"
alalala/bla//blablahistory/somethingnice.istory
alalala/bla//blablahistory/somethingnice.story
alalala/bla//blablahistory/somethingverynice.story
"@

$RE = [RegEx]'/([^/]+)\.story'

$storyName = $notes -split "`n" |
  Select-String $RE -AllMatches | 
    Foreach {$_.Matches.Groups[1]}

$storyName -split "`n"
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SF_852359.ps1
somethingnice
somethingverynice
```

The more complex RegEx as in the question does the following:

- `[^/]` is a negated class matching everything but a slash
- `[^/]+` the trailing plus means at least one of the previous.
- `([^/]+)` the enclosing parentheses mark the first (and here only) capture group
- `/([^/]+)\.story` the leading slash and the trailing literal `.story` frame the word we are after.
- Results of a Regular Expression **survice** at least one pipe level and are accessible through the $_.Matches object, the capture groups being numbered from 1

Comment: thanks for this answer. before marking it as the correct answer could you please put an explanation for the `[regex]` and `foreach` parts? this way other users will easily understand your answer :) I would also mention that `Select-String \w+.\.story -input $notes -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches -replace ('\.story','')}` works as expected in this case :D

Comment: Ack I simplified the ForEach ab bit and added an explanation. When working with multiple groups on a line to rearrange dates for example this comes in handy.